# How to run PathBuf::new with an argument

Tags: rust

Given:

```
PathBuf::new("foo.txt")
```

I get an error:

```
this function takes 0 parameters but 1 parameter was supplied [E0061]
```

Shouldn't it work, given that the method with the argument is listed in the API documentation, under he section [Methods from Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#deref-methods). The few methods I've checked from that section work with **PathBuf**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods listed under [*Methods from Deref*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#deref-methods) are only applicable when calling methods on a `PathBuf` object. This section describes methods that are implemented on `Path`, but that are available thanks to the `Deref<Target=Path>` trait implementation on `PathBuf`.

The `new` method does not take `self` as an argument, so `Deref` does not apply (I think it's a bug that this method is listed here). I suspect you did not pay attention to the method's signature: it returns a `&Path`, not a `PathBuf`. That would have told you that the method is unrelated to `PathBuf`.

Answer (score 3):

While it is indeed not possible to call `Path::new()` method over a `PathBuf` because it is static, the correct way to obtain a `PathBuf` from a string is just to use the generic conversion:

```
let p: PathBuf = "foo.txt".into();
```

This is possible because `PathBuf` implements `From` for everything which can be converted to a reference to `OsStr`:

```
impl<'a, T: ?Sized + AsRef<OsStr>> From<&'a T> for PathBuf
```

And `&str` does implement `AsRef<OsStr>`.